# sharing files on two different systems

Tags: windows-xp

I am trying to share a folder between an XP machine and a windows 7 machine. I am able to share the folder and access it from the windows 7 machine, but I would like to add user level security to the folder. I made sure that the same user is defined on both systems but unless the "everyone" group is added under share I am unable to access the share. any thoughts would really be helpful

Comment: How did you define the 'same user'? Same user name (will not work), same user ID, or \othercomputer\user ?